# Python module not getting deleted properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Somehow I ended up installing 2 different modules named 'google'. One is present in **site_packages** folder inside python, and the one in my custom path provided in **PYTHONPATH**.
I wanted to get rid of the one in site_packages. So I deleted that folder (as per other SO answers). But now, I am facing this weird scenario that it still loads the wrong on at start

```
>>> import google; google.__path__
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google']
>>> google.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
>>> reload(google)
<module 'google' from '/custom_path/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/__init__.pyc'>
>>> google.__path__
['/custom_path/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google'
>>> google.__file__
'/custom_path/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/__init__.pyc'
```

So basically, first time it's still loading the old module (with no files in it), and on reloading, it's giving the correct one.

My question is how to delete the old one completely as it's not feasible to always reload module like this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that somehow other modules were holding a reference to the google module. I removed all packages from google and re-installed them and it worked perfectly after that. I am not yet sure why & how the module was still being referenced, so would appreciate if anyone can throw light to that as well.